# What are the theoretical limitations of Wine?

Tags: wine

Is it theoretically possible for all Windows applications to run through Wine?
I know that Wine is far from perfect (but actually really good) and there are lots of applications that don't run because the implementation is limited.
But would it be theoratically possible to have a 'perfect' implementation that supports every Windows application out there? Or are there any limitations by design? Is there anything that can't be done because of licensing, technical issues, copy protection etc.? I am aware that Wine cannot provide hardware drivers, so we assume that the hardware is already working on the operating system.

Comment: Its limitations are more practical than theoretical...